# Looping through data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring out how to go about this.

I am trying to dynamically create drop downs in the end. I currently have this working but I am making 4 ajax calls (1 for each category to get its children) which is unnecessary.

My database structure is like so:

Columns: id, name, location, category

Rows sample data:

1, blue, room, color 
2, red, garage, color 
3, ball, yard, toy 
4, truck, box, toy 
5, doll, room, toy

What I am trying to do is first find out all the categories in my table and get a unique value for them. I dont want color listed twice and toy listed 3 times, just 1 for color and 1 for toy as they are both unique.

Next, I need to loop through everything again and say Here are all the names under each category.

Result would look like:

Color = Blue, Red 
Toy = Ball, Truck, Doll

```
function makeDataPointsTest() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "../db_api.php",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'xml',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            sp: "Watson_DataPointsList",
            type: "xml",
            params: {
                category: ''
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        },
        success: function(data) { //This is the data I am getting back from the database.
                                          // It is returned as an XML object.

            var dataTmp = []; //temporary array
            var dataCats; //var to hold the unique categories

            $(data).find('dataPoints').each(function(i) { //Node of XML is called DataPoints.

            var tmp = $(this).find('category').text(); //In each Node (row) find the category name
                dataTmp.push(tmp); //Push that category name to an array

                });

            dataCats = _.uniq(dataTmp); //using underscore.js I now have each unique category in                                                       //the database



            //Here is where I am stuck
            //I now need to loop through each node again and create an array that contains each of             //the names under each of the categories.

            }

    });

}
```

Results structure (data):

```
<root>
  <dataPoints>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Blue</name>
    <location>Room</location>
    <category>Color</category>
  </dataPoints>
  <dataPoints>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Red</name>
    <location>Garage</location>
    <category>Color</category>
  </dataPoints>
  <dataPoints>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>Ball</name>
    <location>Yard</location>
    <category>Toy</category>
  </dataPoints>
  <dataPoints>
    <id>4</id>
    <name>Truck</name>
    <location>Box</location>
    <category>Toy</category>
  </dataPoints>
  <dataPoints>
    <id>5</id>
    <name>Doll</name>
    <location>Room</location>
    <category>Toy</category>
  </dataPoints>
</root>
```

Is there an easy way to go about doing this jquery at this point?

**This is what I am trying to create dynamically**

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Emec.png

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about just traversing your data once and placing the data into a map? The keys would be the category names, and the values would be an array of items found in that category.

For example:

```
var categoryMap = {};

$(data).find('dataPoints').each(function(i) {
        var category = $(this).find('category').text();
        var name = $(this).find('name').text();

        // If first time seeing category, create an empty array.
        if (!categoryMap[category]) 
            categoryMap[category] = [];

        // If it isn't already found in the array, add it.
        if (!categoryMap[category].indexOf(name) != -1)
            categoryMap[category].push(name);
});
```

This of course would only store the names within the arrays, but you can also store, say, an array of Objects that includes all this information. The map would allow quick lookup for any object within a category, and you'd only have to traverse your data once.

Comment: How would I be able to access all of the cols in the row if needed? I am building a drop down menu and need to be able to access multiple fields to do so. It will dynamically create multiple drop downs, 1 for each unique category it finds. Then all of the rows that are in that category will become the options in that drop down if that makes sense.

Comment: I would recommend creating an object that encapsulates the data for each row, and then storing that into the array in the map. Then for each category, you can grab the array of objects found in that category, and use that information to generate your select tags

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a function to extract the required data

```
function getUnqVals(data, key){
    var dataTmp = []; //temporary array
    var dataCats; //var to hold the unique categories

    $(data).find('dataPoints').each(function(i) { //Node of XML is called DataPoints.

        var tmp = $(this).find(key).text(); //In each Node (row) find the category name
        dataTmp.push(tmp); //Push that category name to an array

    });

    return _.uniq(dataTmp);

}
function makeDataPointsTest() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "../db_api.php",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'xml',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            sp: "Watson_DataPointsList",
            type: "xml",
            params: {
                category: ''
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        },
        success: function(data) { //This is the data I am getting back from the database.
            // It is returned as an XML object.

            var dataCats; getUnqVals(data, 'category');//var to hold the unique categories
            var dataNames; getUnqVals(data, 'name');//var to hold the unique categories


            //Here is where I am stuck
            //I now need to loop through each node again and create an array that contains each of             //the names under each of the categories.

        }

    });

}
```

It has a problem with, multiple iterations through the `data`, so another veriosn could be

```
function makeDataPointsTest() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "../db_api.php",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'xml',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            sp: "Watson_DataPointsList",
            type: "xml",
            params: {
                category: ''
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        },
        success: function(data) { //This is the data I am getting back from the database.
            // It is returned as an XML object.

            var catsTmp = [], namesTmp = [];
            var dataCats, dataNames; //var to hold the unique categories

            $(data).find('dataPoints').each(function(i) { //Node of XML is called DataPoints.
                var $this = $(this);
                catsTmp.push($(this).find('category').text()); //Push that category name to an array
                namesTmp.push($(this).find('name').text()); //Push that category name to an array

            });

            dataCats = _.uniq(dataTmp); //using underscore.js I now have each unique category in                                                       //the database
            dataNames = _.uniq(namesTmp);



            //Here is where I am stuck
            //I now need to loop through each node again and create an array that contains each of             //the names under each of the categories.

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: How can I pair the values together? I'm essentially building multiple drop down menus. Each Category is its own menu and then each of the records that are tied to that category are its options.

So I need to build it like this:
`
<select name="unique category 1">
<option id="+ROW ID+" name="+CATEGORY+"> + NAME + </option>
<option id="+ROW ID+" name="+CATEGORY+"> + NAME + </option>

</select>

<select name="unique category 2">
<option id="+ROW ID+" name="+CATEGORY+"> + NAME + </option>
<option id="+ROW ID+" name="+CATEGORY+"> + NAME + </option>

</select>`